# Value of the field not used

Tags: android

[image]I am getting this problem in my android application as an "value of the field is not in used". 
actually i am trying to play the sound here when user swipes the page but it continuously giving me this error. this my code.

package com.android.learning_numbers;

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Numbers extends Activity {

    private static final OnPageChangeListener mOnPageListener = null;
    public static MediaPlayer mp = null;

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);
         ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
         ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
         viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
         viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mOnPageListener);

     }

     private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

         private int[] mImages = new int[] {R.drawable.no1,R.drawable.no2,R.drawable.no3,R.drawable.no4,R.drawable.no5,R.drawable.no6,R.drawable.no7,R.drawable.no8,R.drawable.no9,};


         private int[] mAudio= new int[]{R.raw.one,R.raw.two,R.raw.three,R.raw.four,R.raw.five,R.raw.six,R.raw.seven,R.raw.eight,R.raw.nine,};
         @Override
         public int getCount() {
         return mImages.length;
           }
         @Override
         public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((ImageView) object);
               }
         @Override
         public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Context context = Numbers.this;
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            int padding =context.getResources().  
            getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin);
            imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
            imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0); 
            return imageView;
            }

         public OnPageChangeListener mOnPageListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

             @Override public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                 //for Sound 
                 if (mp != null) {
                     mp.reset();
                     mp.release();
                 }
                 mp = MediaPlayer.create(Numbers.this, mAudio[position]);
                 mp.start();
             }
             @Override public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}
             @Override public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}

         };



         @Override
         public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
           ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
         }
     }
     }
```

Comment: Why not `mp = MediaPlayer.create(Numbers.this, mAudio[position]);` at the top of if block

Comment: Which line is it giving error?

Comment: Value of what field?  Sounds like a warning not an error.  If if is an error, please post your stacktrace

Comment: @Gautham Yes it is a warning but due to this i am unable to play sound. the warning is on first line of code (mOnPageListener) on this it is saying it is unused

Comment: @user2310289 see i posted screenshot of this

Comment: Where are you placing this code snippet? Inside onCreate method?

Comment: You created a listener as in `mOnPageListener`. You need to attach this listener so it can get a call back. Seems like you haven't done that.

Comment: Yes, so you have created a listener but not attached it to an object.

Comment: @Sundeep i have done that also like this see the last line of this code  (

 
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);
         ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
         ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
         viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
         viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mOnPageListener);
         
     })

Comment: @Surajdedhia Eclipse shouldn't complain in that case. Have you tried debugging? It's the best way to figure out the problem.

Comment: @Sundeep It's debugging correctly but my problem is to play sound which is not accomplished

Comment: In the screenshot you posted the variable is in the Adapter sub class inside the Numbers class. Is that the activity class from where you took the onCreate() code from? May be you are looking in the wrong place. You need to post full code to save time.

Comment: Code seems fine to me. Check if the audio resource you are passing is fine. For the sake of testing, use the same file, something like `MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
` and test to see if sound plays. Then change the source as required.

Comment: @Sundeep you mean i should try to rename my sound file?

Comment: No need to rename. Instead of pointing from array, point to a fixed file that plays for some length. Its not sure how many pages you are using for testing too. Use log statements to verify that your code is being called.

Comment: Also update your post to reflect the correct question. I believe Eclipse stopped complaining by now.

Comment: @Sundeep It also not working for me. I have put seperate file of audio instead of from array.